# javascript countdown timer - need a second digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got handed a piece of existing javascript and asked to modify it by my boss - trouble is, I barely know my way around javascript at all - our back end developer quit unexpectedly, and I'm just trying to help out.

I need to make it so this countdown timer always displays double digits (01 instead of 1).  I've searched here and tried some of the similar question solutions, but they're all rather specific to the individual question and I'm not having any luck at all making changes using if else if statements (partly because my js understanding and syntax is not good.)  Hopefully it's a easy fix for someone who knows what they're doing!  Thanks in advance.

```js
<script>
// creating a reusable CountDownTimer class with TargetDate

/*
 targetDate = Expiration date
 displayCountDownOnElement = on what element you need the countdown displayed at.
 hideOnExpire = on what element you need to hide when it expires.
*/
  var CountDownTimer = function(targetDate, displayCountDownOnElement, hideOnExpire){
  var target_date  = new Date(targetDate).getTime();
  var countdown = document.getElementById(displayCountDownOnElement);
  var hideExpire = document.getElementById(hideOnExpire);
  
  // variables for time units
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
  
  
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
  function timer() {
 
      // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
      var current_date = new Date().getTime();
      var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

      // do some time calculations
      days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
      seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

      hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
      seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

      minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
      seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

      // format countdown string + set tag value
      countdown.innerHTML = days + " : " + hours + " : "
      + minutes + " : " + seconds + " ";  
    
      if(seconds_left < 0) { 
        hideExpire.style.display = "none";
        countdown.innerHTML = "";
      }
    
  }
}


// Sample Timer to Dec. 1, 2014 1:30:00 PM 
var c = new CountDownTimer("Dec 1, 2014 1:30:00 PM GMT -0800","cyber-timer", "cyber-timer");

</script>
```

Demo here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPzwQg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```
  if(days < 10){days = "0" + days;}
  if(hours < 10){hours = "0" + hours;}
  if(minutes < 10){minutes = "0" + minutes;}
  if(seconds < 10){seconds = "0" + seconds;}
```

before this:

```
  // format countdown string + set tag value
  countdown.innerHTML = days + " : " + hours + " : "
  + minutes + " : " + seconds + " ";
```

Comment: I love how this is a W3Schools classic example! Too bad they seem to have changed the original example to `d.toLocaleTimeString();`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  I added a function to convert the numbers to 2 digit strings if the value is < 10.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/hh13ewLa/

Edit 1:

```
countdown.innerHTML = makeTwoDigit(days) + " : " + makeTwoDigit(hours) + " : "
  + makeTwoDigit(minutes) + " : " + makeTwoDigit(seconds) + " ";
```

Edit 2:

```
function makeTwoDigit(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  }
  return num;
}
```

New Source:

// creating a reusable CountDownTimer class with TargetDate

```
/*
 targetDate = Expiration date
 displayCountDownOnElement = on what element you need the countdown displayed at.
 hideOnExpire = on what element you need to hide when it expires.
*/
  var CountDownTimer = function(targetDate, displayCountDownOnElement, hideOnExpire){
      var target_date  = new Date(targetDate).getTime();
      var countdown = document.getElementById(displayCountDownOnElement);
      var hideExpire = document.getElementById(hideOnExpire);

      // variables for time units
      var days, hours, minutes, seconds;


      timer();
      var interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);  // give interval a reference

      function timer() {

          // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
          var current_date = new Date().getTime();
          var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

          // do some time calculations
          days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
          seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

          hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
          seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

          minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
          seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

          // format countdown string + set tag value
          countdown.innerHTML = makeTwoDigit(days) + " : " + makeTwoDigit(hours) + " : "
          + makeTwoDigit(minutes) + " : " + makeTwoDigit(seconds) + " ";  

          if(seconds_left < 0) { 
            hideExpire.style.display = "none";
            countdown.innerHTML = "";
            clearInterval(interval);  // clears interval 
          }

      }
        function makeTwoDigit(num) {
          if (num < 10) {
            return "0" + num;
          }
          return num;
        }
}



// Sample Timer to Dec. 1, 2014 1:30:00 PM 
var c = new CountDownTimer("Dec 1, 2014 1:30:00 PM GMT -0800","cyber-timer", "cyber-timer");
```

Comment: Stopping the interval would be also awesome

Comment: also very helpful, and multiple solutions are helping me figure out what I was doing wrong.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: Anytime.  Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatToLeadingZero(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  } 
  else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

so you can go like

```js
countdown.innerHTML = formatToLeadingZero(days) + " : " + formatToLeadingZero(hours) + " : "
                      + formatToLeadingZero(minutes) + " : " + formatToLeadingZero(seconds) + " ";
```

This will only work for positive numbers of 1 or 2 digits... so make sure you test it